# CodeIgniter form validation not showing due to redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this edit page that has gets its id and status from uri segments. The problem is that if the user doesn't select an image or complete a part of the form, the page is supposed to reload and show the validation errors for the form. However that page reload causes the data in the form to go missing. Is there a way to solve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I attached my view, and controller

View

```
<?php if($edit == "false"){
        echo form_open_multipart('Control/Products/ProductDetail/addProduct','class="productdetail"');
 }else{
        echo form_open_multipart('Control/Products/ProductDetail/editProduct','class="productdetail"');
       }?>
                            <label for="inputproductname">Product Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputproductname" name="inputproductname" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                            <label for="inputproductdescription">Product Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputproductdescription" name="inputproductdescription" placeholder="Description" rows="7" 
                            ><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>
                            <label for="inputproductprice">Product Price</label>
                            <input type="price" class="form-control" id="inputproductprice" name="inputproductprice" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                            <label for="inputproductimage">Product Image</label>
                            <p><input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="upload" id="upload" aria-describedby="fileHelp"></p>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputcurrentid" name="inputcurrentid" value="<?php echo $currentid; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="inputcurrentstatus" name="inputcurrentstatus" value="<?php echo $currentstatus; ?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                     <?php if($edit == "false"){
                         echo "Add";
                      }else{
                          echo "Edit";
                      }?>
             </button>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>Control/Products/Products">Cancel</a>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<p><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('Form'); ?></p>
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
      $productid = $this->uri->segment(5);
      $editstatus = $this->uri->segment(6);
      if($editstatus == "false"){
          $data['name'] = '';
          $data['description'] = '';
          $data['price'] = '';
          $data['edit'] = "false";
          $data['message']='';
          $data['currentid'] = '';
          $data['currentstatus'] = '';
      }else{
          $product = $this->ProductsModel->getProduct($productid);
          foreach ($product as $productdetail){
            $data['name'] = $productdetail->name;
            $data['description'] = $productdetail->description;
            $data['price'] = $productdetail->price;
          }
          $data['edit'] = "true";
          $data['message']='';
          $data['currentid'] = $productid;
          $data['currentstatus'] = $editstatus;
      }
      $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationLink');
      $this->load->view('control/controlProducts/productDetail',$data);
      $this->load->view('control/controlMenu/navigationJquery');
    }

public function editProduct(){
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductname', 'Name', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductdescription', 'Description', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputproductprice', 'Price', 'trim|required');
      if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
      {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('upload', 'Image', 'required');
      }

      $inputproductname = $this->input->post('inputproductname');
      $inputproductdescription = $this->input->post('inputproductdescription');
      $inputproductprice = $this->input->post('inputproductprice');
      $inputdateadded = date('Y-m-d');
      $inputcurrentid = $this->input->post('inputcurrentid');
      $inputcurrentstatus = $this->input->post('inputcurrentstatus');

      $config['upload_path'] = $this->getProductImageFolderPath();
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png'; 
      $config['max_size'] = 3000;  
      $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
      $config['file_name'] = $inputproductname;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);


      if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
          redirect('/Control/Products/ProductDetail/index/'.$inputcurrentid.'/'.$inputcurrentstatus);
        }else{
          if(!$this->upload->do_upload('upload')){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('Form',$this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('Control/'.$this->getCurrentModule().'/'.$this->getClassName());
          }else{
              $extension = $this->upload->data('file_ext');
              $productdetails = array(
                'name'=>$inputproductname,
                'description'=>$inputproductdescription,
                'price'=>$inputproductprice,
                'imagePath'=>$config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'].$extension,
                'dateAdded'=>$inputdateadded
              );
              $this->db->trans_start();
              $this->ProductsModel->editProduct($productid,$productdetails);
              $this->db->trans_complete();
              if($this->db->trans_status()===false){

              }else{
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('Form', $inputproductname . ' has been altered on the database');
                  redirect('/Control/Products/Products');
              }
          }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($this->form_validation->run()==false){ 
redirect('/Control/Products/ProductDetail/index/'.$inputcurrentid.'/'.$inputcurrentstatus);` 
I think the problem with this redirect stmt don't use it instead you need to use load view so that it will preserves the errors array.

Comment: Yeah I know. But if i use $this->index() my prefilled form data will be lost

Comment: No no, you need to use `set_value('inputproductname', 'value if any'))` in your view to reset input's value.

Comment: I ended up using sessions to store my variables and unsetting them when the update was completed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just do ths in your controller

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('field', form_error('field', '<span class="text-danger pl-3">', '</span>'));

        redirect("url");
    } else {
        # code...

    }
```

and in your redirect page use

```
<?= $this->session->flashdata('field'); ?>
```